# Se input tiver apenas espaços em branco, não fazer nada

Tags: javascript, jquery, espaço-em-branco

Estou fazendo uma aplicação de *chat* com *WebSocket*.

Usei `contenteditable="true"` numa `<div/>`, pois precisei colocar assim para facilitar em outras funções.

Na parte do *`input`* que envia a mensagem para outros usuários estou com um problema, quando o usuário digita apenas espaços em branco e clica em enviar, a mensagem é enviada, mas quero que quando ele digite apenas espaços em branco não envie a mensagem.

Alguém por favor poderia me ajudar a fazer este código em JavaScript ou com Jquery mesmo?

**HTML**

```html
<div id="message" contenteditable="true">Digite sua mensagem</div>
```

**jQuery**

```js
// ENVIA COM O ENTER
$('#message').on('keydown', function(e) {

    var mymessage = $('#message').text(); //get message text
    var myname = $('.myname').text(); //get user name
    var mensagem = 'mensagem='+mymessage;
    var to = $(this).attr('id');
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;

    if (e.which == 13 && e.shiftKey == false) {
        if (code == 13) {
            if (mensagem != '') {
                //$(".mensagens-unitarias").animate({"scrollTop": $('.mensagens-unitarias')[0].scrollHeight}, "fast");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url : 'sys/teste.php',
                    data: 'nome='+myname+'&mensagem='+mymessage,
                    success: function(html){}
                });

                if (mymessage == "") { return false; }

                //prepare json data
                var msg = {
                    message: mymessage,
                    name: myname,
                    color : '<?php echo $colours[$user_colour]; ?>'
                };

                //convert and send data to server
                websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));        
            }
        }

        return false;   
    }
})
```

Comment: Podes colocar o código que faz essa verificação? ou o código que envia esse input?

Comment: Posso sim. Veja a pergunta editada.

Comment: Se não me engano é possível validar somente com HTML5, usando o atributo *pattern* de um `input`. Mas como está fazendo isso em um div, o jeito é utilizar JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução passa por verificar duas coisas:

- Se o tamanho da *string* é rigorosamente igual a nada fazendo uso da propriedade [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length):

  ```
  string.length === 0
  ```
- Se após remover espaços em branco a *string* está vazia, fazendo uso do método [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

  ```
  !string.trim()
  ```

## Exemplo

Exemplo também disponível no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/0851hvxf/).

```js
$(function() {

  var $target = $('#message');

  $target.on("keyup", function() {

    var value = $target.text();

    if (value.length === 0 || !value.trim())
      return false;

    // continuar...
    alert(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message" contenteditable="true">Digite sua mensagem</div>
```

No exemplo em cima, vai surgir um alerta do navegador com o valor introduzido se esse valor tiver algo diferente de espaços em branco.
Se digitares 1 ou mais espaços em branco, não vai acontecer nada.

**Nota:** Em uso o evento [`keyup`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) para disparar o código após a tecla digitada e não quando vamos para digitar uma nova, obtendo maior coerência entre o que está escrito no ecrã e o que o código está a utilizar para trabalhar.

Answer (score 1):

Testa mudar

```
if(mensagem != ''){
```

para

```
if(!mensagem.match(/^(\s)+$/)){
```

Essa expressão regular vai testar esse texto procurando garantir que a no inicio do texto (`^`) existe espaço em branco (`\s`) na quantidade de 1 ou mais (`+`) e que depois disso o texto termina (`$`). E depois nego o match com `!` no inicio dessa condição, ou seja para garantid que esse if só dá true se não houver match.

Acho que isso resolve o teu problema.

Comment: Não deu certo :(

Comment: @DavidDamasceno muda mais 1 coisa: usa o `keyup` em vez de `keydown`. Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/hLk37a3a/

Comment: obrigado, seu exemplo utiliza match, valeu ;)